# Grouping classes in Rails app documentation with Yard

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, documentation, yard

Is there a plugin to format documentation in a way that makes sense for a Rails Application?

I've been trying to use Yard but it puts all of the Model and Controller classes under the top level namespace. Is there any way to get it to treat them as Modules so they all get grouped together?

The structure I'm going for is the same way a rails app is normally structured ie

```
-Models
----ModelClass1
----ModelClass2
----ModelClass3
-Controllers
----ControllerClass1
----ControllerClass2
----ControllerClass3
```

But the what the yard documentation generator spits out is

```
-ModelClass1
-ModelClass2
-ModelClass3
-ControllerClass1
-ControllerClass2
-ControllerClass3
```

Comment: are you talking about the "class list" on the left side of the yard doc's webpage? That hierarchy is determined by namespacing ... so maybe you could create a namespace for your models and controllers, e.g. `Models::ModelClass1`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same goal and raised an issue in the YARD GitHub. They pointed me to the aws-sdk gem that used a custom class list menu structure. I managed to use that to create a generic Rails layout that roughly mimics the folder structure of `app/`.

You can check out my code under step 3 in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/aseroff/1535c132e01300680592a48d4c636106) (you may need to back up to step 2 to create the template directory structure if you haven't yet).